# Comparing in_array values

Tags: php

I have a array of val which has dynamic strings with underscores. Plus I have a variable $key which contains an integer. I need to match $key with each $val (values before underscore).

I did the following way:

```
<?php
    $key = 2; //always a dynamic number
$val = array('3_33', '2_55'); //always a dynamic string with underscore
if(in_array($key, $val)) {
    echo 'Yes'; 
} 
else
{
    echo 'No';  
}
?>
```

Though this code works fine, I want to know if its a correct way or suggest some better alternative.

Comment: Your code would output `no` - is it intended? If so, what actually do you expect simpler than a single function call?

Comment: But what's wrong with using this existing code? This is clean and recommended by PHP Manual itself, so why look for complicated versions. Theoretically there are "better" ways of doing everything, but that is subjective

Comment: since you need to match only the part before the underscore, you should use a regex match or a string match. the above code shouldn't work although you say that it works. hmmm... see answer below

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
foreach( $val as $v ) 
{
    if( strpos( $v , $key .'_' ) === true ) 
    {
        echo 'yes';
    }
    else {
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

Comment: although i +1d this, you should note that since strpos will return 0 if the match is found, you should do the comparison using ===. so it should be changed to if( strpos( $v .'_' , $key ) === true)

Answer (score 1):

use this function for regex match from php.net

```
function in_array_match($regex, $array) {
    if (!is_array($array))
        trigger_error('Argument 2 must be array');
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        $match = preg_match($regex, $v);
        if ($match === 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
   return false;
}
```

and then change your code to use this function like this:

```
$key = 2; //always a dynamic number
$val = array('3_33', '2_55'); //always a dynamic string with underscore
if(in_array_match($key."_*", $val)) {
    echo 'Yes'; 
} 
else
{
    echo 'No';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = 2; //always a dynamic number
$val = array('3_33', '2_55'); //always a dynamic string with underscore
$inarray = false;
foreach($val as $v){
    $arr = explode("_", $val);
    $inarray = $inarray || $arr[0] == $key
}
echo $inarray?"Yes":"No";
```

Comment: `$val` is an array, not a string

Comment: @zerkms Right, missed that. Thanks.

Comment: 1. It's php5.4 only 2. It's a huge overcomplication. `strpos($val, $key) === 0` - would do the job better 3. you probably want to `break;` after you find entry.

Comment: Seeing your answer, I'm confused with the answer that I gave. I thought the OP wanted to check the value before the underscore, did I misunderstand the question ?

Comment: @zerkms Point 2 is wrong, by the way. `strpos` is fooled by numbers that begin with the same digits but aren't exactly the same. Searching for `2` in `"25_55"` for example.

Comment: @jerome.s: no one knows for sure. Read the last OP's phrase: "Though this code works fine"

Comment: @Asad: not a big deal - append `$key` with underscore and it still will be better than explode. At least it will be more semantic: the string starts with... is more correct than - the first array item matches with...

Comment: @zerkms That is subjective. The OP is using strings to represent a key value structure, so I don't agree that using strpos is "more correct".

Comment: @Asad: it's not subjective. The value is a string that starts with lookup key followed by underscore and some "dynamic" value. It's very straightforward to check if a string starts with key if you need to check if it starts with key. There is a choice - to create a temporary array only one item of which will be used or not. I think the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
    function arraySearch($find_me,$array){
$array2 =array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $val = explode('_',$value);
    $array2[] =$val[0]; 
}
$Key = array_search($find_me, $array2);
$Zero = in_array($find_me, $array2);
if($Key == NULL && !$Zero){
    return false;
}
return $Key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The given format is quite unpractically.

```
$array2 = array_reduce ($array, function (array $result, $item) {
     list($key, $value) = explode('_', $item);
     $result[$key] = $value;
     return $result;
}, array());
```

Now you can the existence of your key just with `isset($array2[$myKey]);`. I assume you will find this format later in your execution useful too.